# Angular Bootstrap tabs not getting input field

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Facing a weird issue, where a simple text field value is not getting printed when using tabset. Wrote a sample to demo the same. Please check it below link

[sample link](http://plnkr.co/edit/JczXnsFj9MZR9kpyBVn5?p=preview)

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title">Testing input
    <input ng-model="nameStr" value="">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg " type="button" ng-click="callMe()" >Test callme</button>
    </tab>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
      {{tab.content}}
    </tab>
    <tab select="alertMe()">
      <tab-heading>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
      </tab-heading>
      I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

Do suggest, what would have been missed out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some questions about `angular-ui` way of encapsulate controllers inside it's directives (the idea is to have different controllers for different tasks). The problem, to access your "original" controller (and not the ones in the ui-bootstrap directive) you have to use the `$parent` in your view. Because the current `$scope` inside `tabset` is pointing to another controller.

So, it will become

```
<input ng-model="$parent.nameStr" value="">
```

I couldn't find the right explanation in the angular-ui repo, but this seems to get some ideas.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2971

**Older Answer**

You can replace the `$scope.nameStr` inside the `$scope.callMe` for `this.nameStr`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cUUQ9FQ0oEOmIltQTS2f?p=preview

Comment: But can you explain the behavior? the nameStr is not in the scope if you try to dump $scope to console.. it is also not available on parent.. but how "this"?

Comment: lol, I know, is little be confused, I'll explain better.. and offer the recommended way for this.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I do get what it mean but may be missing the actual theory. If possble, hint me.

Comment: _this_ solved part of the issue for me, now I have a $scope variable in Controller gets updated in service call and I can't access that value. Any idea on how to solve that

Comment: @user1686758 I updated the answer, try using the new approach, because the `this` is the first way that I used to do this. Take carefully with the `this`, because inside anonymous functions it will have another scope.

Comment: @AbdelRaoof, there is [a big question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers) that show the main different between the `this` and the `$scope`, because is not so easy. The idea here, is that the `this` can access all child scopes (like the defined in the tabset directive), but $scope don't.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
$scope.name = {};
$scope.callMe = function(){
  alert('title ->'+$scope.name.str);
}
```

In html:

```
<input ng-model="name.str" value="">
```

Angular works much better this way. Using `dot` properties.